# FOSElasticaBundle: How to not index offline document?

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I've got a MySQL DB of "documents" being indexed by ElasticSearch with the FOSElasticaBundle for Symfony2 with the console command:

```
php app/console fos:elastica:populate
```

I don't want the documents with column "online" to false being indexed.

What have I to do to configure that need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to add callback during the indexation process to check if an object has to be indexed - or not.

Just add the `indexable_callback` in the config like that:

`types:
       document:
           indexable_callback:         'isIndexable'`

In that case, you have to write a `isIndexable` method in the associated object, for example:

`public function isIndexable() {
        return $this->getOnline() && $this->getPublished();
    }`

Answer (score 1):

You must create a custom Document Loader where you will check whether online is true and if so - return a new document instance.

FosElasticaBundle provides an interface for each document provider called ProviderInterface, you can create a service that implements the interface, tag it as a "fos_elastica.provider".

Kind of like so:

```
<service id="service.id" class="Some\Bundle\Some\Class">
    <tag name="fos_elastica.provider" index="<index>" type="<type>" />
    <argument type="service" id="fos_elastica.index.<index>.<type>" />
    <argument type="service" id="logger" />
    <argument type="service" id="op.search.loader.product" />
    <argument>150</argument>
</service>
```

That service will be responsible for populating a specific indexes type.
The service will implement populate method in which you can write your own logic how you want to populate that type.

Comment: I think it suits more complex needs than the question / use case and I've found easiest solution.